# Is there a "collection-type" equivalent annotation in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, java-ee-6

In Hibernate you can define a custom collection type by setting the "collection-type" attribute in hibernate xml mapping file.

I was wondering if there is an annotation equivalent.

PS: I tried using @Type but hibernate complains:

```
"Illegal attempt to map a non collection as a @OneToMany, @ManyToMany" ...
```

So I assume @Type is just for regular properties.

Thanks!

Comment: So you're saying instead of having e.g. java.util.List you have your own collection type which does not implement one of the Collections interfaces?

Comment: @Geziefer, actually I was trying to use a Glazed Lists "EventList" (http://www.glazedlists.com/documentation/hibernate#TOC-Hibernate-mapping-for-EventLists) instead of a List. I gave up on that idea long time ago: too many "side effects".

Comment: Oops, haven't noticed that your question was from half a year ago. Never heard of it, but I had the feeling that using standard constructs in the O/R mapping always pays off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When this question was made there was no such an annotation. Since [HHH-4417](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-4417) is fixed in version 4.1.1 there is [org.hibernate.annotations.CollectionType](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/CollectionType.html). Though I don't know does it work with mentioned EventList collection.